# How can i remove dd-mm-yyy from date input field when my input is disabled

Tags: html, css, date, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

I have a date input field, in which if the date is not entered and if the field is disabled, it should hide the date format eg."dd/mm/yyyy", but if the date is entered in the field it should show the date regardless the field is enabled or disabled.

So how can check the condition like this.

```
if ( date is empty && field is disabled)
    set Transparent color
```

Things i have tried

```
input[type=date]:required:invalid::-webkit-datetime-edit && input[type=date]:disabled::-webkit-datetime-edit {
    color: transparent !important;
}
input[type=date]:required:invalid::-webkit-datetime-edit.input[type=date]:disabled::-webkit-datetime-edit {
    color: transparent !important;
}
```

https://codepen.io/veer3383/pen/ervYmr

In my current codepan, if the date is not entered it hides the date format if the field is enabled, on disabling the field it shows the format

Answer (score 0):

instead of changing colour, you can simply toggle placeholder attr, if you're using jquery it will be:

```
$input=$( "input[type='date']" );
if($input.prop('disabled')){
    $input.attr('placeholder','');
    /*or change the value using .val() or colour usin .css('color','transparent') */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've Solved it this way.

**CSS**

```
input[type="date"]:focus::before {
    content: none
}

.non-empty-date input[type="date"]:disabled::before {
    content: none;
}

.empty-date input[type="date"]:disabled::before {
    content: attr(data-placeholder);
    width: 100%;
}
```

**Template** (Vuetify framework)

```
<v-text-field :class="[(loan.completionDate === null ) ? 'empty-date' : 'non-empty-date']" required="required" :clearable="!disabled" type="date" :disabled="disabled" v-model="loan.completionDate" label="Completion Date"
max="2999-12-31"></v-text-field>
```